# how to find ‘k’ from this equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If the remainder is $-3$ when $ x^3+x^2+6x$ is divisible by $x+3$?

If the remainder is $4$ when $2x^5+6x-2$ is divisible by $x-2$?

Comment: These statements don't tell you anything about $k$.

Comment: $\,x^3 + x^2 + 6 x = (x^2 - 2 x + 12) \cdot (x + 3) -36\,$ so find a $\,k\,$ (whatever that may be) where $\,-36 = -3\,$. Better yet, edit the question and make it intelligible. Can't fathom who upvoted it.

Comment: @dxiv I only upvoted because I felt bad at the amount of downvotes... :/

Answer (score 1):

**Hint (from what I believe you might mean):**

If the remainder is $-3$ when $x^3 +x^2 + 6x$ is divisible by $x+3$, then there exists $k$ such that $$\begin{align} (k+3)(x+3) &= x^3 +x^2+6x \\ \\ \text{since }\frac{x^3+x^2+6x}{x+3} &= k+r\end{align}$$ for a remainder $r$, and it has been disclosed that $r = -3$.

---

If the remainder is $4$ when $2x^5 + 6x - 2$ is divisible by $x-2$, then...